# replace text within a string

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I want to find a text within the string and replace it but it's not working my code.   I have to mention that i get normally the Title of the webview, but when i output the `text2` i get the whole title (does not replace the text). Also all strings except from `text2` , located within a void.

```
String text1 = web1.getTitle();
String text2 = text1.toString().replace("-Click 2U - Files", "");
```

Thank you in advance....

Comment: It's a very simple google: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/73139

Comment: Can you provide the full title and the actual replacement you are using?

Comment: My guesse would be that your search string gets interpreted as a regex, and you think it is handled as a regular string ?

Comment: why do you call `toString()` on a `String`?

Comment: @C.d. i was checking if bugs for that.... this is not the problem....

Comment: Scenario for me: You set text1 = "" , I think you put it to function - the reference to text1. Then you replace the reference (last line). When the function is finished text1 has old reference (to ""). Use StringBuilder, instead of String. `stringBuilder.setLength(0);stringBuilder.append(text3)`

Comment: What do you get when you print the result of `web1.getTitle()`?

Comment: The code you published is partial, so the real problem is still hiding. 
You can see a running version of the code here: http://ideone.com/C3BVQ
I don't see anything wrong with the `replace` part, something else is not right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code works for me:

```
 String text1 = "some string with -Click 2U - Files in it";
 String text2 = text1.replace("-Click 2U - Files", "");
 // here text2.equals("some string with  in it")
```

This will remove all instances of the string.  You can also use `replaceAll(...)` which uses regular expressions:

```
 String text1 = "some Click 2U title for Clicking away";
 String text2 = text1.replaceAll("C.*?k", "XXX");
 // here text2.equals("some [XXX 2U title for XXXing away")
```

Notice that the `"C.*?k"`pattern will match a `C` and then any number of characters and then `k`.  The `?` means don't do an eager match and stop at the first `k`.  Read your [regex manuals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details there.

Comment: i didn't understand how to use this code ..what does this code assertEquals("some string with  in it", text2); ? thank you

Comment: Sorry, that's just showing you what the output would be.  I'll edit my answer to make that more plain.

Answer (score 0):

I used it for replace password

input

```
{"Login":"login1", "Password":"password1"} 

inputParameters.toString().replaceAll( "(\"Password\":\")+\\w+\"", "\"Password\":\"*********\"") + "\"")
```

output

```
{"Login":"login1", "Password":"*********"}
```